# Getting different output for same comparator for array and priority queue

Tags: java, collections

i am getting different output for the array and priority queue , could you please let me know the reason for it

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class Employee {

private Long id;
private String name;
private int age;
private int salary;

public Employee(Long id , String name , int age , int salary) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.salary = salary;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public int getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public static Comparator<Employee> salaryComparator = new Comparator<Employee>() {
    public int compare(Employee e1 , Employee e2) {
        return e1.getSalary() - e2.getSalary();
    }
};


public static void main(String[] args) {

    PriorityQueue<Employee> pe = new PriorityQueue<>(20, new Comparator<Employee>() {
        public int compare(Employee e1 , Employee e2) {
           return e1.getSalary() - e2.getSalary();
        }
    });

    pe.add(new Employee(1L, "jack", 24, 9));
    pe.add(new Employee(4L, "jill", 40, 12));
    pe.add(new Employee(2L, "jill1", 30, 100));
    pe.add(new Employee(3L, "jack2", 35, 11));

    System.out.println("priority queue " +  pe);


        Employee[] empArr = new Employee[4];
        empArr[0] = new Employee(1L, "jack", 24, 9);
        empArr[1] = new Employee(4L, "jill", 40, 12);
        empArr[2] = new Employee(2L, "jill1", 30, 100);
        empArr[3] = new Employee(3L, "jack2", 35, 11);

        Arrays.sort(empArr, Employee.salaryComparator);

        System.out.println(" array " + Arrays.toString(empArr));

}



@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", salary=" + salary + "]";
}
}
```

output:

```
priority queue [Employee [id=1, name=jack, age=24, salary=9], Employee [id=3, name=jack2, age=35, salary=11], Employee [id=2, name=jill1, age=30, salary=100], Employee [id=4, name=jill, age=40, salary=12]]

 array [Employee [id=1, name=jack, age=24, salary=9], Employee [id=3, name=jack2, age=35, salary=11], Employee [id=4, name=jill, age=40, salary=12], Employee [id=2, name=jill1, age=30, salary=100]]
```

Comment: i believe you're looking for `return Integer.compare(e1.getSalary(), e2.getSalary());`

Comment: @MattClark but in the both the case output should be same for both the scenario right ?

Comment: @Aominè if you're going to suggest better code, why not suggest the _correct_ code - `return Comparator.comparing(Employee::getSalary)`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider or better `Comparator.comparingInt(Employee::getSalary)`, ;)

Comment: @Aominè touche.

Comment: From the [documentation for `PriorityQueue.iterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#iterator()) "_Returns an iterator over the elements in this queue. The iterator does not return the elements in any particular order._" You have assumed that printing (looping over) a `PriorityQueue` provides sorted order **it does not**.

Comment: @Aominè i just want to understand that why output is different when we are using same comparator .